# How to get the query prameters when accepting a websocket connection using axum?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-axum

How do I get the query parameters when accepting a websocket connection using axum?

The following code is used to accept a websocket connection, but how can I get the parameters of the url?

```rust
// Echo back
async fn handle_socket(mut socket: WebSocket) {
    while let Some(msg) = socket.recv().await {
        let msg = if let Ok(msg) = msg {
            msg
        } else {
            // client disconnected
            return;
        };

        if socket.send(msg).await.is_err() {
            // client disconnected
            return;
        }
    }
}

async fn ws_handle(ws: WebSocketUpgrade) -> Response {
    ws.on_upgrade(handle_socket)
}

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/ws", get(ws_handle));

    axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
```

For example, I access via `wscat ws://127.0.0.1:3000/ws?name=aaa&age=18` and want to get the name and age fetch values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other [extractors](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/extract/index.html#common-extractors) alongside `WebSocketUpgrade`. You'd be looking for [`Query`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/extract/struct.Query.html):

```
use axum::extract::Query;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Params {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}

async fn ws_handle(
    Query(params): Query<Params>,
    ws: WebSocketUpgrade,
) -> Response {
    // do something with `params`

    ws.on_upgrade(handle_socket)
}
```